# Yeoman find version of the generator and upgrade

Tags: yeoman

Once an app has been created with a Yeoman Generator, is there a way to find which version of the generator was used ?

And subsidiary question, if a newer version of the generator exists, is it possible to upgrade my existing app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried `yo webapp`, if you look at the first line in `Gruntfile.js` you will see

```
// Generated on 2013-12-11 using generator-webapp 0.4.4
```

I don't think you can update your app with a more recent version of the same generator, since the generator creates a folder structure and a starting point with packages and configurations it would easily conflict.

Generally speaking you are getting a starting point from the generator, upon which you build your application, if you are in need of different packages you just proceed from the starting point in your direction, adding packages, components, etc...